# Inconsistency in cucumber execution

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumberjs, cucumber-java

There are two inconsistencies in my execution.

1) As per the following scenario, "And Click Create Customer" annotation doesn't work correctly. I've updated it before instead of the expression included "@Then("Musteri Olustur tabina tikla ve acilan sayfada submit butonuna tikla")" and once i try to execute it by performing run as feature file with right click, somehow  I'm still getting error about previous annotation (the one starting @Then).

2) Second issue is the sixth step of the scenario is not being executed at all. ("Then Type customer information")

How is this possible ?

First four step is working correctly.

```
Feature: Create Customer
Scenario: Create Prepaid Customer Turkish Citizen
Given Access to LegacyCRM
When Type your username and password
And Click login button
Then Verify that legacycrm is opened
And Click Create Customer
Then Type customer information
```

-

```
   public class CucumberCustomer {

    WebDriver driver;

    @Given("^Access to LegacyCRM$")
    public void AccessLCRM (){

        File file = new File("C:/Users/wiprofkaymaz/Desktop/ie32/IEDriverServer.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",file.getAbsolutePath());
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.get("https://iccbcf/TelsimGlobal/Menu/showLogin.jsp");
    }

    @When("^Type your username and password$")
    public void TypingLoginInformations(){

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='username']")).sendKeys("wiprobaslan");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']")).sendKeys("Voda123456789**");
    }

    @And("^Click login button$")
    public void ClickLoginButton(){
        WebElement login=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@src='/TelsimGlobal/Menu/image3.gif']"));
        login.click();
    }

    @Then("^Verify that legacycrm is opened$")
    public void legacycrmverification(){
        driver.switchTo().frame("ax");
        driver.switchTo().frame("menu");
        boolean vry =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='images/vodafone_logo_top.gif']")).isDisplayed();
        if(vry){
            System.out.println("application has been opened");
        }
        else{

            System.out.println("something wrong");
        }

    }
    @And("^Click Create Customer$")
    public void Customercreatev1(){

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Müşteri Oluşturma']")).click();
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        driver.switchTo().frame("cx");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='Submit']")).click();
    }

    @Then("^Type customer information$")
    public void Customercreatev2() throws InterruptedException{
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        driver.switchTo().frame("cx");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='name']")).sendKeys("KEM");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='lastname']")).sendKeys("KEM");
        Select selectObject = new Select (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='day']")));
        selectObject.selectByValue("10");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        Select selectObject2 = new Select (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='month']")));
        selectObject2.selectByValue("10");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        Select selectObject3 = new Select (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='year']")));
        selectObject3.selectByValue("1950");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        String mainWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='iddistrict']")).sendKeys("ADANA");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='fathername']")).sendKeys("BABA");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='Submit']")).click();
        Windows(driver, mainWindow);
        driver.switchTo().window(mainWindow);

    }

    public void Windows (WebDriver driver, String mainWindow) {

        mainWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
        Set<String> totalwindowsIds = driver.getWindowHandles();
        int a=0;
        String[] myset = totalwindowsIds.toArray(new String[totalwindowsIds.size()]);   
            if(myset[a].contains(mainWindow)){
                driver.switchTo().window(myset[a+1]);
            }
            else{
                driver.switchTo().window(myset[a]);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: execution result is 1 Scenarios (1 undefined)
5 Steps (1 undefined, 4 passed)
0m18.024s


You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

@Then("Musteri Olustur tabina tikla ve acilan sayfada submit butonuna tikla")
public void musteri_Olustur_tabina_tikla_ve_acilan_sayfada_submit_butonuna_tikla() {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new cucumber.api.PendingException();
}

Comment: Note that you don't have a step definition matching the step "Then Verify that legacycrm is opened". Your class includes "@Then("^Type customer information$")". - Also, please update your question with the result, rather than adding it in a comment.